# Does Euler product formula give any hints about asymptotics of primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

From the Euler product formula for $\zeta$ function we get
$$
\sum\limits_n\frac1{n^s} = \prod\limits_p\frac1{1 - p^{-s}} = \mathrm{exp}\left(-\sum_p\log(1 
 - p^{-s})\right).
$$
As $s\to\infty$ we get $p^{-s}\to 0$ so for large $s$ we get $\log(1-p^{-s}) \sim -p^{-s}$ for large $s$ hence (not sure whether that's correct though)
$$
\log\left(\sum_n\frac1{n^s}\right)\sim \sum_p\frac1{p^s}.
$$
Can this be used somehow to derive any non-trivial asymptotics on the growth of $p$, say like the one in the prime number theorem?

Comment: The Euler product formula **IS** used to derive the prime number theorem, as well as most associated stonger bounds and asymptotics.

Comment: Read the first few chapters of Tenenbaum's _Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory_ and you will see

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the limit $s \to \infty$ shouldn't be expected to give asymptotic information, because the contributions from the tail of the series $\sum_{n} n^{-s}$ and $\prod_{p} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}$ are both going to be negligible. However, asymptotic information is all about the tail of the sequences of primes; we want the tail of the series to outweigh the early terms. It's the series that diverge that give us information about the primes. This is why the critical strip of the zeta function is $0 \leq \text{Re(s)} \leq 1$: in that region the Euler product formula diverges, so we can use the rate of divergence to get information about the primes.

To make it more concrete, your identity $\log(\sum_{n} n^{-s}) \sim \sum_{p} p^{-s}$ as $s \to \infty$ is correct, but it's also true that $\log(\sum_{n} n^{-s}) \sim 2^{-s}$, so this asymptotic relation can't distinguish between a sum over all primes and a sum over just the number $2$.